# Multiple custom attributes of the same type found. c# exception in botframework

Tags: c#, azure, exception, skype, botframework

My bot works in an instance in Azure, but when i tried to upload it to another instance, it stopped responding. Am getting the following exception.

Because of this we got rejected from Bot framework.

```
    InternalServerError
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Multiple custom attributes of the same type found.",
  "exceptionType": "System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException",
  "stackTrace": "   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)\r\n   at Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1.get_FrameworkVersion()\r\n   at Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1.SetDefaultUserAgentInfo()\r\n   at Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1.SetUserAgent(String productName, String version)\r\n   at Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1.InitializeHttpClient(HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConnectorClient..ctor(Uri baseUri, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConnectorClient..ctor(Uri baseUri, String microsoftAppId, String microsoftAppPassword, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)\r\n   at HoroscopeBot.MessagesController.<Post>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now this issue has been posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1600#issuecomment-259410883) and it seems the only solution is to delete your current azure instance and create a new instance and upload your code again.
This work around is working for me and others too.

To make it clear,

1. Delete your current azure instance that shows the error.
2. Create a new instance of another name (Using same name gave problem to me. It worked for sometime but later on crashed.)
3. Upload your code to new instance.

This should work as magic.

Please also note that i have deleted the app plan with the instance.

Please comment for any queries.